# Tagging support for Select2 with Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-select2

In attempting to integrate [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) with [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), I noticed that what seems to be [the usual way](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/wiki/Knockout.js-Integration) of doing it does not seem to have [tagging support](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#tags).

There is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drosen/6XvqX/) that illustrates the basic support, but it is not apparent how one would extend this to Select2's tagging support.

I have reduced this to a more concise **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/6XvqX/38/)** that one would expect would form the basis for a solution.

I would be grateful for thoughts and suggestions on how to go about obtaining tagging support for Select2 with Knockout.js.

**Note:** I am not wed to `Select2`, though I think it is brilliant. If however there is an alternative suggestion for tagging support that works well with `Knockout.js`, I would be quite interested in hearing about it. That being said, a solution to the problem with `Select2` would be quite interesting, I think.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems that all the examples "in the usual way" are for `<select>` tags, but tagging support requires an `<input>` tag. This somewhat modifies the analysis. I will post any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tagging feature doesn't work with `<select>` elements as you noted. That's because it allows the user to add tags that aren't in the list. You can type anything in the field and press enter, and it's added to the value.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/6XvqX/41/

Key changes:

1. The list of available items is passed directly to Select2 through a `tags` option.
2. The `value` binding is used instead of `selectedOptions` since the latter only works with `<select>` elements.
3. A computed is used to get the selected items as an array.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddler with a newer version of knockout.js as I couldn´t get the example above to work. This one does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/6XvqX/424/.

```
(no change to the code itself)
```

Anyhow, thanks to Michael for providing the solution. :)